# How to get Visual Studio debugger to break without focus

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to break while my (native C++) application has mouse focus, and by switching to the Visual Studio application to Ctrl-Alt-Break or Debug > Break All, my application is no longer doing the thing I am trying to break on.

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to break after 5 seconds has elapsed for example?  Or is there some kind of debugging api that I can write a script to trigger a Break All without me switching focus to the Visual Studio application?

Being able to break without focus could help with [poor man's profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/1007353) and better understanding unfamiliar code related to focus.

Comment: Visual Studio (especially 2015) has a ton of profiling tools, so if your goal is really to do profiling you would be better off using those.

Comment: It is a supported debugging scenario, you have to run the app on another machine and use the remote debugger.

Comment: You can edit your breakpoint's properties, perhaps you can configure the breakpoint to do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two ways to break without changing mouse focus to Visual Studio:

1. Install [Remote Tools and debug from another machine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx), *OR*
2. Add a thread with a timer and set a break point there, e.g. add this somewhere to break every 5 seconds:

   ```
   static bool debug_timer_started = false;
   if ( !debug_timer_started )
   {
     debug_timer_started = true;
     std::thread([]
     {
       static int seconds = 5;
       static bool keep_going = true;
       while ( keep_going )
       {
         /* set break point on this line: */ std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(seconds));
       }
     }).detach();
   }
   ```

   You will need these headers:

   ```
   #include <thread>
   #include <chrono>
   ```